# html fixed column textarea with wrapping on any char

Tags: html, textarea

I have a need for an html control with fixed number of columns that does wrapping based on any character.  Similar to the very old DOS or Telnet terminals that move to the next line whenever the column is beyond 80.  Normal textarea with CSS `word-wrap: break-word;` and `text-wrap: unrestricted;` did not work.  The latter is not supported in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this works is with n editable div and the following CSS properties.  Tested in Google Chrome:

`word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre;` and the div must have an explicit width.